# Laravel - Four levels deep relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to map a relationship between the User and Order Model within Order Model.

An order has one project. The project has one team and the team has one owner/user

The relationship is four levels deep like following:

**order > project > team > user**

My database tables are as follows:

App\Order

```
id, 
project_id
```

App\Project

```
id, 
name, 
team_id
```

App\Team

```
id
name
user_id
```

App\User

```
id
name
```

My Order Model:

```
class Order extends Model{
    function customer(){
      // trying to map the relationship here
    }
}
```

I would like to access the customer like following:

```
 $order =  Order::find(1);
 echo $order->customer->name;
```

Could you please tell me how to map the above-mentioned relationship?

Comment: Where you stored customer name, on `users` table?

Comment: In users table. App\User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by including joins in your query like:

```php
$data = Order::select('orders.*')
    ->join('projects', 'orders.project_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->join('teams', 'projects.projects_id', '=', 'teams.id')
    ->join('users', 'teams.teams_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->get();
```

For Eloquent you can use this **[package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through)**.

You can  define deeper relationships : 
**Order** → *belongsTo* → **Project** → *belongsTo* → **Team** → *belongsTo* → **User** :

```
class Order extends Model
{
    use \Znck\Eloquent\Traits\BelongsToThrough;

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsToThrough('App\User', ['App\Team', 'App\Project']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The eloquent package did the trick. This solution is more ideal for me since it returns the `$order->customer` as an instance of the User object and so it's all relations are accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to define a `belongsTo` in your model by adding joins to directly reach users table

```
class Order extends Model
{

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'project_id')
            ->join('team as t', 't.id', '=', 'projects.team_id')
            ->join('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 't.user_id')
            ->select(['u.id as uid','u.name','projects.id']);
    }

}
```

And then you can directly get the customer information from order object

```
$order =  Order::find(1);
$order->customer->name;
```

OR
Via eager loding

```
$orders =  Order::with('customer')->get();
```

Comment: Works perfectly. The only downside is since `$order->customer` is not an instance of the User Model you cannot access its relations

Comment: @black_belt Yes that's a compromise for this type of relation